# Connect Postman to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, api, postman

There is a problem.
I need to access Postgres Database from Postman. Database isn't local, it is on a server, but I have full connection string (host, db_name, user_name/password, scheme).
Any chances to do it?
I tried PostgREST, but I can't install it. I have `LIBPQ.dll is not found` error. I installed it but it was no help, I still have `0xc00007b` error.

So that I can't install PostgREST.
Should I install it on the server where DB is located?
And is there any other way?

update: I managed to overcome all the errors (here is the note how to overcome `0xc00007b` error: https://postgrest.org/en/stable/install.html).
Now I can call postgrest from cmd with the flag --help, but it's still not connected to the database. [image]

update2: I managed the connection by putting postgrest.conf filled file in the same directory as postgrest.exe file and running in from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

search for app and browser control in start menu, then select exploitation control :

[image]

set randomize image ASLR to off

[image]

Comment: it will help me to overcome the 0xc00007b error?

Comment: try to turn off all security stuff on that page